# Estou com problema de print em Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Estou fazendo um código que verifica se uma expressão matemática é válida, mas não apenas a quantidade de parênteses, mas a expressão como um todo. Criei uma função mas não está printando.

```
ex = str(input('Digite uma expressão: ')).strip()
operadores = ['+', '*', '/', '-', '**']
abre = ['(', '[']
fecha = [')', ']']
def casos1(): # ERROS DE COMEÇO
        if ex[0] == fecha: #Abre de jeito errado com ) ou ]
            print('Sua expressão está ERRADA.')
        if ex[0] == operadores: #Começa com operadores
            print('Sua expressão está ERRADA.')

casos1()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`abre`, `fecha` e `operadores` são listas. O que significa que se tu tentar comparar um caractere com elas, nunca o resultado vai ser verdadeiro.

Dada a expressão inválida ")*":

Quando tu faz o teste `ex[0] == fecha`, o que tu realmente está fazendo é comparando `')'` com `[')', ']']`.

Para comparar uma string com todos os elementos de uma lista, o Python tem a abordagem de testar se uma string está contida em uma lista (operação matemática contém):

```py
def casos1(): # ERROS DE COMEÇO
    if ex[0] in fecha: #Abre de jeito errado com ) ou ]
        print('Sua expressão está ERRADA.')
    if ex[0] in operadores: #Começa com operadores
        print('Sua expressão está ERRADA.')
```

Veja também mais sobre [operações com listas](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), sobre as funções [any()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#any) e [all()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#all) e também o módulo [re](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html).